# De Ranke XXX Beer

Tags: ipa, ibu

From beer advocate, it says that the XXX beer from De Ranke brewery is **no longer brewed**. (http://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/739/97035/). It's no longer on their brewery page too: http://www.deranke.be/en/bieren_en.htm

It's not exactly the kind of belgium kind of belgium pale ale, famous for their bitterness, it's normally criticized for being too bitter in normal crowd-source reviews.

Sometime ago I saw this tweet that says XXX scored an IBU 70 (https://twitter.com/beergusto/status/435908275863687168).

**Does anyone has any more information on the XXX?**

**And also how can I get hold of one now?** **Is there like a beer amazon or something?**

Comment: https://belgiuminabox.com/shop/home/3972-de-ranke-xxx-bitter.html they seem to have it. They also state the reason why it's no longer brewed.

Comment: its still on their page, in Dutch at least. I know for a fact they're still brewing the XX Bitter, because they have it at my favourite bar.

Answer (score 1):

They are brewing it actively and there's information on the deranke.be website at http://www.deranke.be/en/bier/xxx-bitter

[image: a screenshot of the website info on the XXX-Bitter]

Comment: I went to several craft beer shops that sells XX and every time I arrived it's the same story of a few days/weeks/months ago, they sold their last bottle of XXX =(